# Select text in node with Xsl:value-of but leave text of children out

Tags: xslt

I have the following piece of XML that I need to transform into an image tag:

```
    <surface xml:id="EETS.T.68">
        <label>Verse 68<note place="bottom" anchored="true" xml:id="informational">In
                Bodleian Laud 683, BL Harley 218, and BL Harley 2255 this verse is prefaced
                with the Latin "dic anime mee salus tua ego sum" [“Say to my soul, you are
                my salvation”], from Psalm 34:3. It is part of a five-stanza sequence
                treated in this manner in those texts, but only three of the verses appear
                at Long Melford.</note>
        </label>
        <graphic url="ww_test_5.jpg"/>
    </surface>
```

Using the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:graphic" mode="list">
    <a class="nav_link">
            <img class="thumbnail">
                <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../tei:label"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </img>
        </a>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

I use the label elsewhere in my transform, so I can't really move elements around, but what I'd like to have happen is that it forms something like this:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="../../Testament/Clopton/Thumbnails/ww_test_5-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Verse 68"/>
```

(note:I have deleted the thumbnail and src attributes above as it was confusing people)

Instead, the note contents are also included so I get this:

```
<img class="thumbnail"
                                src="../../Testament/Clopton/Thumbnails/ww_test_5-thumbnail.jpg"
                                alt="Verse 68In&#xA;                        Bodleian Laud 683, BL Harley 218, and BL Harley 2255 this verse is prefaced&#xA;                        with the Latin &#34;dic anime mee salus tua ego sum&#34; [“Say to my soul, you are&#xA;                        my salvation”], from Psalm 34:3. It is part of a five-stanza sequence&#xA;                        treated in this manner in those texts, but only three of the verses appear&#xA;                        at Long Melford."
                             />
```

I looked at some of the similar questions but they don't seem to really work for my use case. I've tried using `text(not[*])`, but that suppresses everything when there's a note element rather than just the note element itself. I'm also not sure xsl:copy-of is a viable option since I'm trying to get the content of a sibling node (and thus move up a level before selecting tei:label rather than selecting it directly.). When I've tried to use it it hasn't returned a result at all.  Is there a way to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select only the first text child node use `<xsl:value-of select="../tei:label/text()[1]"/>` or for the first child node `<xsl:value-of select="../tei:label/node()[1]"/>`.

Comment: That did the trick!  I swear I tried 'text()[1]' but I must have formatted it differently.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is very confusing. I think (!) you are trying to get only the text node that is a direct child of `label`? That could be done by changing:

```
            <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                <xsl:value-of select="../tei:label"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
```

to:

```
            <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                <xsl:value-of select="../tei:label/text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Sorry for being confusing. Usually when I strip things down I get flack for leaving context out. If I leave it in, I get flack for adding too much.  I've removed extraneous attribute constructors.

what I need is actually everything but the children of 'label'.

Comment: Your expected result shows `"Verse 68"`. That is a text node that **is** a child of `label`.